# Using JQuery to display Firebase query results in a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase-realtime-database

I have a HTML search form in my website's header where users can search a Firebase database collection. When the user clicks the search button to submit the query, they'll be taken to a new page with their search results.

I'm running into an issue where the page is not redirecting and the console does not show any data being returned from the query. I've searched all over for an example of how to do this but haven't found anything. I appreciate any help with this.

HTML search form

```
<form id="navsearchform">
    <input type="search" id="searchnav" placeholder="Keyword, City"/> 
    <button id="navsearchbtn" class="wtsearchbtn">Search</button> 
</form>
```

JQuery search function

```
var fireQuery = function () { 
    var queryData = $("#searchnav").val(),
        dbRef = firebase.database().ref(),
        eventsRef = dbRef.child('events'),
        sendQuery = eventsRef.orderByChild('description').equalTo(queryData);

        sendQuery.once('value', function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {
                // data to be displayed
            var resultsTitle = snapshot.val().title,
                resultsDesc = snapshot.val().description,
                resultsPic = snapshot.val().image;
                console.log(resultsTitle);

            // redirect to results page
           window.location.href = "results";

            // display search results on results page
            // append the results to div
            var $resultsdiv = $( '<div>+resultsTitle+</div>' ); 
            $("body").append( $resultsdiv ); 

            }); 
        });  
    };

    $(window).load(function () {
        $("#navsearchform").submit(fireQuery);
    }); // end window load
```

Database structure

```
{
  "events" : {
    "-KrStHa_NoQnheYJ2121" : {
      "description" : "[redacted]",
      "title" : "[redacted]",
    },
    "-KsV3TsI0KcQAnPbSyWf" : {
      "description" : "[redacted]",
      "title" : "[redacted]",
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you redirecting to the results page after doing the query? How could you see the results then without rerunning the query on that new page, in which case you should just do the query on the results page only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the results to be displayed on the new page then you have to run the query on the new page, not on the current page.

So you will want to submit the results directly to the new page, you do not even need firebase on the search page.

Something like this would work.

#### search.html

```
<form action='results.html' method='GET'>
  <input type='search' name='description' placeholder='Keyword, City' />
  <button>Search</button>
</form>
```

#### results.html

```
<div id='results'></div>
<script>
  // This is a script I use to get the URL parameters submitted via a "GET" method.
  var $_GET=function(){var a={};if(location.href.indexOf("?")>-1){var b=location.href.split("?")[1];b.indexOf("#")>-1&&(b=b.split("#")[0]);for(var c=b.split("&"),d=0;d<c.length;d++){var e=c[d].split("=")[0],f=c[d].split("=")[1];a[e]=f}}return a}();

  firebase.database()
    .ref("events")
    .orderByChild("description")
    .equalTo($_GET.description)
    .once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot){
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
        var result = childSnapshot.val();
        var $result = document.createElement("div");
        $results.innerHTML = "<p class='title'>"+result.title+"</p><p class='description'>"+result.description+"</p>";
        document.getElementById("results").appendChild($result);
      });
    });
</script>
```